# Remove parallax effect from revolution slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, revolution-slider

I have a Revolution slider plugin on my website and it has some kind of effect or something that when I scroll it moves up and down and I don't know how to remove it, I don't have access to the plugins configuration either.

So far I've tried with jQuery/js to move it down a little bit but when I scroll it keeps moving.

```
document.getElementById("rev_slider_3_1_wrapper").setAttribute("style", "margin:15px auto 80px;padding: 0px;max-height: 740px;left: -105.5px;position: absolute;width: 1351px;overflow: visible;height: 521px;");
```

This puts the slider 15px down but when I move the scroll it moves all around and breaks my layouts, is there anything I can do?

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: That's quite hard to solve blind. All we know is that there is "something" that "moves", it's difficult to find a fix.

Comment: it's all I know too.

Comment: you have a link for a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revolution Slider allows you to enable/disable parallax effects due the options which you can add to the initialisation script.

To **enable Parallax**:

jQuery('#slider').show().revolution(
    {

```
    delay:16000,
    startwidth:1170,
    startheight:700,
    hideThumbs:200,

    parallax:"mouse",
    parallaxBgFreeze:"on",
    parallaxLevels:[10,7,4,3,2,5,4,3,2,1],

});
```

To **disable Parallax** effect simple remove any parallax based option like this:
jQuery('#slider').show().revolution(
    {

```
    delay:16000,
    startwidth:1170,
    startheight:700,
    hideThumbs:200

});
```

Note, there are over 40 options you can set due the slider initialisation, and you may want to have different options also enabled/disabled, so i would recommend to get the full documentation by following the link: http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-jquery-plugin/2580848

Also, all questions about Revolution Slider can be answered here: http://www.themepunch.com/support-center/

Hope this helps you further !?